# How to echo the literal string "-e" (and nothing else) in bash?

Tags: bash, escaping

How can I `echo` the literal string `-e` and nothing else?

I'm trying to better understand how shell arguments are escaped.

The following commands do not work:

```
echo -e # prints nothing
echo '-e' # prints nothing
echo "-e" # prints nothing
echo \-e # prints nothing
echo \\-e # prints \-e
echo '\-e' # prints \-e
echo "'-e'" # prints '-e' (with quotes)
echo -- -e # prints -- -e
```

I can't find one that doesn't either include quotes or a leading slash.

Comment: `printf '%s\n' -e`?  It doesn't use `echo` but does print the result you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming the real question is why:

A C# or Java function can never behave differently based on whether you invoked it as `foo(4)` or `foo(2+2)` or `foo((int)16/4)` because that information is gone by the time the function runs. It can tell *what* you passed, but it can't tell *how* you passed it.

For the same reason, a command can never behave differently based on whether or how you escaped its arguments. Quoting and escaping is a *how*, while the resulting string argument is the *what*.

Here is the equivalent `execlp` call of each of your attempts (`echo` is builtin in bash but behaves the same):

```
#    v-- How you passed it            v-- What you passed
echo -e     # execlp("echo", "echo", "-e", 0);   # prints nothing
echo '-e'   # execlp("echo", "echo", "-e", 0);   # prints nothing
echo "-e"   # execlp("echo", "echo", "-e", 0);   # prints nothing
echo \-e    # execlp("echo", "echo", "-e", 0);   # prints nothing
echo \\-e   # execlp("echo", "echo", "\\-e", 0); # prints \-e
echo '\-e'  # execlp("echo", "echo", "\\-e", 0); # prints \-e
echo "'-e'" # execlp("echo", "echo", "'-e'", 0); # prints '-e' (with quotes)
echo -- -e  # execlp("echo", "echo", "--", "-e", 0);   # prints -- -e
```

As you can see, the *how* doesn't affect output at all. It all comes down to the *what*. This is why all the escaping in the world will fail to have the intended effect.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I didn't really think through what `echo` was receiving :-) In that case, I guess `echo` simply doesn't implement a means to escape would-be flags, whereas other apps manually support `--` for such scenarios?

Comment: Exactly. It can't really use normal conventions because POSIX disallows it for historical reasons, and due to this and other historical portability problems it recommends `printf` instead

Answer (score 6):

> How to echo the literal string "-e" (and nothing else) in bash?

```
printf '%s\n' '-e'
printf -- '-e\n'
```

From [man echo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) `-e` is an option:

> -e
>   enable interpretation of backslash escapes

From [bash builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html):

> echo
>   ...
>   If the -e option is given, interpretation of the following backslash-escaped characters is enabled.
>   ...
>   echo does not interpret -- to mean the end of options.

So `echo -e` will  make echo interpret `-e` as a flag and print empty newline.
To print `-e` you basically have to use `printf` (or you can use an implementation of `echo` that will allow to do that). I don't believe it is possible to print only `-e` with bash echo builtin.

`printf` is more portable. There are implementations of `echo` which do not take `-e` argument and it may work. On the net you can find [various sites](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/echo+printf/) about echo portability issues.

Answer (score 3):

```
 echo -e '\x2de'
```

Not very readable, but it works

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using `awk` and a Bash C style string and a 'here string':

```
$ awk '1' <<< $'-e' 
-e
```

Works without quotes (if that is your goal):

```
$ awk '1' <<< -e
-e
```