# Bash script won't accept -e as a parameter

Tags: bash

I have a simple script:

```
echo $1
echo $2
```

Running it as `./example.sh -x -e` produces the following output:

```
-x
```

Running it as `./example.sh -e -x` produces the following output:

```
-x
```

Running it as `./example.sh -t -x` produces the following output:

```
-t
-x
```

So as you can see, `-e` is always dropped.

I can't find anything online about this. Note I'm using a Mac.

Any ideas?

Comment: HInt: What do you get when you execute `echo -e`?

Comment: Try `printf "%s" "$1"`

Comment: See: [How to echo the literal string “-e” (and nothing else) in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54102155/3776858)

Comment: Thanks guys. Seems so obvious now but it never occurred to me it was because of echo. Doh!

Comment: Note that any version of `echo` that doesn't print `-e` on output is violating the POSIX sh specification. bash's violates the spec by default, but this can be turned off (at compile time, or with environment variables at runtime, or with appropriate `set` and `shopt` options at runtime), so you can't safely rely on it either way.

Comment: ...there's a really excellent answer to a related question on our sister site [unix.se]; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113